# C++ regex_replace issue

Tags: c++, regex, std

Why this code does not replace the 'Mozilla/5.0' to 'My User Agent'?

The Regex works fine in Notepad++ but does not work in my console app.

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string header = 
"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\
Host: com.com\r\n\
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n\
Connection: keep-alive";

    tr1::regex rx("^(User-Agent:).+$", regex_constants::icase);
    header = regex_replace(header, rx, "$1 My User Agent", regex_constants::format_first_only);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? regex C++11 was not fully supported until very recently. It may be that Notepad++ is using a different compiler from your console (this is in case you don't get a compilation error)

Comment: I use VS 2012. 
Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2012 (v110)

Comment: Are you getting an error when compiling with VS? Or nothing happens?

Comment: No, no errors. But the header was not changed.

Comment: When you say "works fine in Notepad++", you mean you are compiling a program with Notepad++ and it works? Or you are using the regex in Notepad++?

Comment: I mean that find & replace works in Notepad++ with 'Regular expression' switch enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `^` means beginning of **string**, not beginning of **line**.
You can use the following regex, which works fine:

```
((?:^|\r\n)User-Agent:).+(?=$|\r\n)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]